# MYSQL sum of multiple columns returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SUM((((((((((`generalSum`.`total` + `FFBHARVESTINGsum`.`total`) + `PRUNINGsum`.`total`) + `FIELDMAINTENANCEsum`.`total`) + `PESTDISEASEsum`.`total`) + `PLANTINGSUPPLYINGsum`.`total`) + `BUILDINGCONSTRUCTIONsum`.`total`) + `INFRAMAINTENANCEsum`.`total`) + `NURSERYsum`.`total`) + `TRANSPORTATIONsum`.`total`)) AS `totalOfall`
```

The above seems to return null, i have tried coalesce but that doesn't help either. the tables are all views, could that cause an issue?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have way too many parentheses in your expression -- but that doesn't affect the results, only the readability and maintainability.

The `SUM()` returns `NULL` only when the expression in the `SUM()` is `NULL` on *all* rows.  This is because `SUM()` ignores `NULL` values, so if even one expression result were not `NULL`, then the `SUM()` would be not `NULL`.

The expression will be `NULL` if *any* of the values on a row is `NULL`.  That is because adding `NULL` to any value returns `NULL` -- in contrast to `SUM()`.  So, I assume that one or more of the values are `NULL` in any given row.

You can fix this by replacing `NULL` values with `0` using `COALESCE()`:

```
sum( coalesce(generalSum.total, 0) + 
     coalesce(FFBHARVESTINGsum.total, 0) +
     coalesce(PRUNINGsum.total, 0) +
     . . .
   )
```

This has nothing to do with using a view *per se*.

Comment: Fantastic that works, thank you. Is that unique to MYSQL or have i somehow avoided this in MsSQL? Thanks for the informative answer.

Comment: @Tosm . . . Not at all.  All of this is standard SQL and true in any database.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the value is NULL. If that, whole sum equals NULL.

Wrap every column in

```
IFNULL(value, 0)
```